# How do I recognise which client machine sends print request to printer on server?

Tags: c#

How do I detect that which client sends the print request to printer? When a request is sent to server which event will be raised on the server for this print request? I want to detect which user is printing how many pages in a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WMI to monitor the printer.

WMI Tasks: Printers and Printing
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Win32_PrintJob
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Watch for instance creation of print jobs.  PrintJob class has a totalPages.

Use System.Management to use WMI in C#